# Excel pivot table help to calculate days

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am working with Excel 2013, but will hopefully have access to the power query function in a few months. (My network Enterprise people are difficult.) Anyway I have a table that shows a kind of tracking system between 2 teams:

```
Item#     Team1_In  Team1_Out   Team2_In   Team2_Out
DE0009J   9/2/20    9/3/20      9/5/20     9/30/20
PS1230K   9/1/20    9/5/20      9/6/20     9/8/20
TE0009W   8/27/20   9/2/20      9/3/20     9/15/20
```

The end state is to have a doughnut chart that shows the average days each team has an item number for each month. Can you help me get there? One way is to have a hidden column that calculates the NetWorkDays for each team, but that won't do me much good if this is in a table that is added to on a daily basis, because I don't want to have to manually copy the formula down every day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your table of data a Table (or ListObject).  Select the table of data for your pivot table source and press ctl+t to convert it into a Table (ListObject). Now your formulas will propagate as your data gets added.  You may have to re-copy/paste your existing formulas to get the Table to propagate your formulas, but once you have it working, it will allow you to use your hidden column formula.